# Set ValueAxis ( Kendo Line Chart) Min, Max value in my typescript file dynamically

Tags: angular, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am adding a Kendo-line-chart in my Angular(4) component like below,

```
<kendo-chart>
<kendo-chart-value-axis > 
              <kendo-chart-value-axis-item  [title]="{ text: 'Temperature' }"
                                          [min]="minVal"  [max]="maxVal"  >
              </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
          </kendo-chart-value-axis> 

           <kendo-chart-category-axis>
              <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="month" >
              </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
          </kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-series>
          <kendo-chart-series-item type="line" [data]="seriesData" field="temperature"  categoryField="month" [name]= "temp-month"  [markers]="{ type: 'square' }">
          </kendo-chart-series-item>
        </kendo-chart-series>
             </kendo-chart>
```

The issue is when I am trying to set the "min" and "max" value
of `<kendo-chart-category-axis-item>` via my tyscript variable, it just does not bind. If I set the min="10" and max="100" than it works just fine. So basically hard-coded values are working fine but DOES NOT work when I bind the min and max property with my TS variable. It is weird for me. Can some one please help??
I do have two variable in the ts file as below,

```
minVal:any = "10",
maxVal:any ="200"
```

Comment: not sure if this would help, what about minVal: number = 10?

Comment: I resolved the issue. Pleas see my comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using the Kendo-chart control **k-rebind**  attribute. I passed an json object like {min:10,max:80} to this **k-rebind** attribute. I was setting this json object using the bindings to the properties of my TS file. if any of the json object property changes than kendo-chart will rebind/redraw chart on UI. if json object does not change than no-redraw( render method would not call of kendo-chart).

Comment: Hello Akash can you share your code snippets for idea i have same issue

Comment: I have this project  at the following location, you can use it,  https://github.com/githubakash007/Angular1.5Kendo

Comment: Let me know, if you still have any question on this.